# Need to upload image more than 2MB

Tags: php

I had changed the quota in PHP.ini to 10 MB for upload_max_filesize . I could not upload a image more than 2MB in PHP.

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You should should check the settings of your server first. are they correct and is more than 2MB?

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```

if it is lower, you can change it via

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');
```

or via htaccess (if its allowed on your server)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Just to be cmplete, you can edit your **php.ini** settings to

```
upload_max_filesize = 8M
post_max_size = 8M
```

---

another thing to check is if your form code has the correct attributes

```
 method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Indeed. You can then try to adjust them using `ini_set()`. Or from `.htaccess` if `ini_set` fails

Comment: without changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`,firstly is it possible to upload the file of size more than `upload_max_filesize`?. Is there any chance to resize the image of size more than `upload_max_filesize`? without changing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to change following variables into your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize from 2MB to 4MB or 8MB
```

2) Or you can set it into php file as well

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '4M');
```

3) Or you can also use .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4M
```

Comment: Setting them in the script after the upload has finished won't have much of an effect.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set upload_max_filesize in php.ini file

Comment: without changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`,firstly is it possible to upload the file of size more than `upload_max_filesize`?. Is there any chance to resize the image of size more than `upload_max_filesize`? without changing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

And see next lines in php.ini:

```
max_execution_time 
max_input_time 
set_time_limit
```

becouse you can have bad connect with server.

Answer (score 0):

Need to edit php.ini file. and set the   `upload_max_filesize` to your own

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue has been fixed. I just restart my server. Now its working