# PHP move_uploaded_files() function not working with pics sizes more than 2MB

Tags: php, function, upload

Peace be with you all, I have an issue that is whenever I try to use the function

`move_upload_files()`
I find it working perfectly with images less than 2MB and I have modified my php.ini and used `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');` and every time I restart wamp services and it's still the same, only uploading files less that 2MB only! any suggestions?

Comment: what errors appears ?

Comment: Check post_max_size as well. And var_dump $_FILES to see what error it might report.

Comment: thank you all, i found that my error is that i was modifying php.ini file inside the wamp root, when i tried it with php.ini through wampserver platform itself, it worked, thank u all

Answer (score 2):

`move_uploaded_files()` does NOT care how big (or small) the uploaded files are. It simply moves them. Most likely  you've got a system-set upload limit causing the uploads to be aborted. Since you're here asking this question, it implies you have absolutely NO error handling in your upload script and simply assume that all uploads will always succeed.

a) You need to increase your upload limit. This has to be done at the php.ini level (or httpd.conf/.htaccess). The various settings are listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

b) You need to add error handling, to catch when uploads DO fail. Something like

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']);
}
```

is the absolute bare minimum. The available error codes are detailed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change some other settings. Check the settings by using this code:

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```

if it is lower than 10M, you can change it via

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

or via htaccess (if its allowed on your server)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Just to be complete, you can edit your php.ini settings to

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Another thing to check is if your form code has the correct attributes

```
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12685461/2701758